# What it the BIOS Serial Number Maximum length?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, hardware, bios

I am developing an activation application, which I need to collect the BIOS serial number to identify the PC,
the Application combine the BIOS serial Number to other data, which will be encrypted,
I need my data not to exceed the block size of the encryption to prevent building another block which means a longer activation string.
I need to make sure that the BIOS serial number's length will not exceed a certain value, if it is less, I can add some data, but if it exceeds I cannot trim it since I need to make sure there is no activation key works for two PCs.

My question simply is: What is the maximum length of the BIOS Serial number ?
and how I can get these standards?

P.S. doing trim made us a great problem since there are some serials are too longer than the requested value, so there exists a key running more than one PC.

Regards,

Comment: You may apply md5 check sum on the s/n and have always a code with the same length ...

Comment: Caution, some OEMs do not set the BIOS serial number. We recently ran into a site where more than one computer had a BIOS serial number set to "**Value to be set by OEM**". Consequently, our application license worked on the two computers and the customer used one license to run our software on multiple computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these standards are defined in the [`SMBIOS tables`](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_2.7.1.pdf) and AFAIK there is not a maximum or fixed length for the BIOS serial number, this is just a null terminated string.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using such BIOS information is always critical as there are many implementation. And even if you find an standard for this there is no guarantee that every vendor implements it properly.
I would do an hash function (SHA256, MD5, whatever) over the data. So you'll always have the same output length independent form the input length.
Of cause the entropy of the output can never be larger then the entropy of the input. But that's not a (the) point here.